# SQL Server Query equivalent of excel formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

In my excel cellA to F are holding integer values.

IF(COUNTIFS(cellA:cellD,">0")=0,0,IF(COUNTIFS(cellA:cellD,">0")<=IF(AND(OR(cellE>=0),
cellE>0,cellF>0),1,0),"Y",0))

How can I convert the above excel formula into MSSQL query.
Note: In my SQL table named “MyData” the columns are as below and in brackets are corresponding cells in my excel.

[image: My data in table]

Comment: Please describe the logic you want to implement and show the results.

Comment: Import excel to sql server using by import data tools in sql server

Comment: @Amirhossein data is already in SQL imported using SSIS package. now looking for a way to have the this same formula now in excel now in a SQL query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the idea is in excel COUNTIFS(cellA:D) will give me 0 where it's greater and then does a comparison here:IF(COUNTIFS(cellA:cellD,">0")<=IF(AND(OR(cellE>=0), cellE>0,cellF>0),1,0),"Y",0)). to give "Y" or "0". This was done by someone in excel but they need the same output in an SSRS report from a SQL server database and data is already imported. Basically want to translate the formula in SQL. I don't know much of excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this below script works for you or not. If not, some adjustment should done the trick for you as all logic are there that you can be re-used

```
SELECT 
CASE         
    WHEN 
      (
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellA)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellB)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellC)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellD)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) = 0 
    THEN "0"
    WHEN
      (
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellA)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellB)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellC)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellD)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) <= (CASE WHEN 'CollE(CellE)' > 0 AND 'CollF(CellF)' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    THEN "Y"
    ELSE "0"
END
FROM your_table_name
```